# FFMpeg-PHP Headers Not Found on CentOS / cpanel

Tags: php, ffmpeg, nasm, centos6, ffmpeg-php

I have looked all over for directions on how to install. I have followed the guide at ffmpeg(dot)org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos FFMpeg works fine as I have been able to convert an mp3 and mp4. My issue is when I try to setup FFMpeg-PHP. When I run **./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php-config** ffmpeg-php I am getting two errors.

- configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
- checking for ffmpeg headers...
  configure: error: ffmpeg headers not found. Make sure ffmpeg is compiled as shared libraries using the --enable-shared option

**FFMpeg Info**

ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)

**FFMpeg-PHP Output**

```
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/include/php -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/include/php/main -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/include/php/Zend -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/include/php/ext -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for ffmpeg support... yes, shared
checking whether to force gd support in ffmpeg-php... no
checking for ffmpeg headers...
configure: error: ffmpeg headers not found. Make sure ffmpeg is compiled as shared libraries using the --enable-shared option
```

I am not sure if this is related but I am also having an issue running yum update.

```
root@cvp259 [/]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, tsflags, universal-hooks
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 67.222.0.10
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 67.222.0.10
 * base: centos.unixheads.org
 * epel: pubmirror2.math.uh.edu
 * extras: repos.dfw.quadranet.com
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: mirror.steadfast.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nasm.x86_64 0:2.07-7.el6 will be updated
---> Package nasm.x86_64 0:2.13.01-0.fc24 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) for package: nasm-2.13.01-0.fc24.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nasm-2.13.01-0.fc24.x86_64 (nasm)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any help would be appreciated.